# How to show Success Message then refresh the webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to refresh the web page after saving the form data to SQL.

When saving the data the success message is displayed.  But a soon as I add this code

```
Response.Redirect("../Clients/NewClient.aspx");
```

The page then refreshes without he success message.

I know I am doing something wrong here but not sure what?

Here is my code I am using:

```
 conn.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(@"connstring", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", txtCompanyName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmailAddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContactNumber.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WebAddress", txtWebSite.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Toastr.ShowToast("Client Information Saved Successfully", "Success", Toastr.Type.Success);
        Response.Redirect("../Clients/NewClient.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is telling the browser to redirect to another page, and ignore any output coming from the current response. So you either display that message on the target page, or you put some Javascript into the current response which navigates the user to newClient.aspx (using window.location) after they have clicked OK on the message. Or you run this save operation via AJAX, display the message on successful ajax response, and then redirect to the new page that way.

Comment: ... and it's usually bad design to mix business logic and web logic in the same method/class.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your success message include an okay button and then redirect users once that button is clicked:

```
//If user clicks okay then they are redirected to new page
//if user clicks cancel then nothing happens
ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;

string strconfirm = "<script>if(window.confirm('Client Information Saved Successfully')){window.location.href='../Clients/NewClient.aspx'}</script>";
CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
```